# Access binaries inside docker

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, docker

I am using Meteor and [Meteur Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) package to push a bundle to server. It uses docker. The problem is that I cannot access graphicsmagick or imagemagick from inside a docker to use it in my app. However it is installed on the server and I can access it when typing gm command. How can I make it accessable?

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile and Start commands or à reproducer ?

Comment: can you run `which gm` in container, and provide the output. Is gm command installed in other path? you need set `RUN PATH="/opt/GM_PATH:$PATH"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be configurable at the moment based on this [open issue](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/434). However, you could always fork the project and modify the [start script](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/blob/mupx/templates/linux/start.sh) to use your own custom docker image. If so, make sure you make it:

```
FROM meteorhacks/meteord:base
```

Comment: Thanks, I added these 2 lines in each if statement inside a start script 
meteorDockerId=`docker ps | grep meteorhacks/meteord:base | awk '{print $1}'`
docker exec $meteorDockerId apt-get install graphicsmagick -y
and it works

Comment: Perfect, that works too. Just keep in mind that you'll lose those binaries next time you bring up a new container.

Comment: Oh nvm, if you're adding it to the start script it should be fine. It will just take a little longer to come up each time. You should be fine.