# Meteor Up Docker and Graphicsmagick

Tags: meteor, docker, graphicsmagick, meteor-up

I'm looking for how to install Graphicsmagick at Meteor Up Docker.

I found this solution ([Access binaries inside docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877328/access-binaries-inside-docker#comment49799635_30878942)) but I couldn't make work, where do I put those lines at `start.sh`?

```
meteorDockerId=docker ps | grep meteorhacks/meteord:base | awk '{print $1}'
docker exec $meteorDockerId apt-get install graphicsmagick -y
```

That's my `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

APPNAME=instagatas
APP_PATH=/opt/$APPNAME
BUNDLE_PATH=$APP_PATH/current
ENV_FILE=$APP_PATH/config/env.list
PORT=80
USE_LOCAL_MONGO=0

# remove previous version of the app, if exists
docker rm -f $APPNAME

# remove frontend container if exists
docker rm -f $APPNAME-frontend

set -e
docker pull meteorhacks/meteord:base

if [ "$USE_LOCAL_MONGO" == "1" ]; then
  docker run \
    -d \
    --restart=always \
    --publish=$PORT:80 \
    --volume=$BUNDLE_PATH:/bundle \
    --env-file=$ENV_FILE \
    --link=mongodb:mongodb \
    --hostname="$HOSTNAME-$APPNAME" \
    --env=MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongodb:27017/$APPNAME \
    --name=$APPNAME \
    meteorhacks/meteord:base
else
  docker run \
    -d \
    --restart=always \
    --publish=$PORT:80 \
    --volume=$BUNDLE_PATH:/bundle \
    --hostname="$HOSTNAME-$APPNAME" \
    --env-file=$ENV_FILE \
    --name=$APPNAME \
    meteorhacks/meteord:base
fi


  docker pull meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server:latest
  docker run \
    -d \
    --restart=always \
    --volume=/opt/$APPNAME/config/bundle.crt:/bundle.crt \
    --volume=/opt/$APPNAME/config/private.key:/private.key \
    --link=$APPNAME:backend \
    --publish=443:443 \
    --name=$APPNAME-frontend \
    meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server /start.sh
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Re-installing the graphicsmagick package every time you re-start the containers seems like a hack I wouldn't want to do.

If you're modifying the start script already, might as well use a Dockerfile:

```
FROM meteorhacks/meteord:base
RUN apt-get install graphicsmagick -y
```

Then modify `start.sh` template to build a new docker image with graphicsmagick, tag it and use that image instead:

see: https://gist.github.com/so0k/7d4be21c5e2d9abd3743/revisions

EDIT: Where to put Dockerfile?

`start.sh` template is copied to `/opt/<appName>/config/`, currently the Dockerfile would need to be in that same directory (`/opt/<appName>/config/Dockerfile`)

see [Linux init Task](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/blob/b2d356ab5da1334c049fcb5c3e711d754071e2ce/lib/taskLists/linux.js#L72)

**Alternatively**, you can specify specific Dockerfile with the `-f` flag for the [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/docker/reference/commandline/build/)

Or **your third option** is to pipe Dockerfile to `docker build` using a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix-Shells)

I've updated the [start.sh gist](https://gist.github.com/so0k/7d4be21c5e2d9abd3743), we no longer pull the meteord:base image and build it instead:

```
docker build -t meteorhacks/meteord:app - << EOF
FROM meteorhacks/meteord:base
RUN apt-get install graphicsmagick -y
EOF
```

The `docker build` will run every time, but as long as the requirements aren't changing, docker will use the docker images it cached.

Comment: I couldn't find where to put my Docker file. I putted at `/opt/instagatas/config` and `/opt/instagatas` but I'm seeing this message `Cannot locate Dockerfile: Dockerfile`. Where do I put it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your comment where to put the Dockerfile, I think it might actually be better to pipe the contents to the `docker build` command within the start.sh template.

Comment: I tried the third option and it worked if I use `mupx restart`, but when I do `mupx deploy` the `start.sh` change back to original, so I need to change the file again and restart. Theres a way to this don't happen?

Comment: did you make the change to start.sh in the template folder or in the `/opt/.../config` folder? You should change the start.sh **template**

Comment: I chagend at `/opt/.../conf`, I couldn't find the template file, where do I find it?

Comment: I guess in your **global** npm directory? If you installed mup globally `npm install -g mup`

Comment: awkwardly this didn't work for me - do i have to somehow reset mupx first?

Comment: In global .npm/mupx directory I only have 2 files: package.tgz and package/package.json. Can you pls explain how to modify start.sh file in the template? Thanks

Comment: For me it was in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mupx/templates/linux/start.sh

Comment: @PhilippSpo is the real MVP here.  Thanks a ton, how do we make this a config?  is there a fork that already does it?

Comment: @mackbrowne - things changed since this question was asked and it is indeed a bad idea to modify your local mupx copy (your changes will be lost on updates). I personally don't use mupx, I just have experience with Docker & npm. If this functionality is required, somebody may fork and do a pull request to handle this instead...

Comment: @VincentDeSmet Thanks for this, Easy short term solution is to fork mupx and then just keep it updated regularly with this single file change.  Maybe I'll build it out into a feature and PR it back into the main repo.  Thanks for the inspiration yo.  Also your avatar is dope!

Comment: my avatar is only a rip from little dicky bc ppl say I look like him, honest!

Comment: mupx show me a npm deprecated message and failed to install gm for me.

Answer (score 3):

The *development Version* of Meteor Up at [Kadirahq](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up) allows specification of a custom Docker Image in the config file (`mup.js`).

MeteorD-Images with Graphicsmagick installed are available on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/ianmartorell/meteord-graphicsmagick/).

This got me a working deployment (Meteor 1.3.2.4, Meter Up [309cefb](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up/commit/309cefb376e8e1b2b98c4d9347a20b368487a4cc), Node v5.4.1):

**mup.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  …
  meteor: {
    dockerImage: 'ianmartorell/meteord-graphicsmagick',
    …
  },
};
```

Comment: Did you have to download this docker image somewhere, or did you just make this change in the mup.js file and it worked?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the docker image that @bskp mentioned to work, so I figured out how to write one that uses abernix/meteord:base and then has graphicsmagick installed. Very simple, but it seems to be working for me on Meteor 1.4.1.1

I just did this in my mup.js file

```
docker: {
  image: "joshjoe/meteor-graphicsmagick",
},
```

This was a huge pain to get working, so I'd be happy to help anyone who is struggling with this.

https://github.com/c316/meteor-graphicsmagick

Answer (score 0):

If the *if  statement* successes, you should be able to see a running container corresponding to the image you are *grepping*. In my opinion you can add the two lines after the *fi* to obtain the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Build an image for get [things right](https://github.com/kadirahq/meteor-up/pull/71#issuecomment-237885002/), but you can do temporary:

```
docker exec -it MeteorAppName apt-get install imagemagick -y

docker restart MeteorAppName
```

Check imagemagick: `docker exec -it MeteorAppName convert -version`