# Change Meteor Up start.sh template

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

Due to install Graphicsmagick at Meteor Up Docker, I need to edit the `start.sh` (link this: [Meteor Up Docker and Graphicsmagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901697/meteor-up-docker-and-graphicsmagick/31903981#31903981)).

I done that at the server and works, but every time I run `mupx deploy`, my `/opt/<appName>/config/start.sh` file change to original. I need to change the `start.sh` template, but I don't know how to do that, how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the file from your local meteor-up template. not sure about mupx, it might be in your global .npm installation folder.

I'm using kadira meteor-up so mine is located at the git cloned folder.