# MupX, graphicsmagick and env var

Tags: meteor, docker, meteor-up

In following the answer in this question

[Meteor Up Docker and Graphicsmagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901697/meteor-up-docker-and-graphicsmagick)

I'm still having a problem with the cfs:graphicsmagick package finding the gm executable. Do I need to export an env var in the start.sh file?

Here's the relevant section of start.sh

```
set -e
docker build -t meteorhacks/meteord:app - << EOF
FROM meteorhacks/meteord:base
RUN apt-get install -y graphicsmagick
EOF
```

Comment: Is this the only bit of the file you have modified? if it is you need to change any reference in the if/else statement below it for meteord:base to meteord:app. I also found I had to comment out the following lines to ensure it made the new box instead of using the existing one initially

    #set +e
    #docker pull meteorhacks/meteord:base